# convolution of experimental data with a singular function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution

this is likely a few lines of code but I cannot figure it out...
I need to perform a convolution operation of experimental data with an analytical function which is singular at the beginning of the integration range. So if I use "conv" it won't work...

I have two experimental vectors, `phi(time)` and time
then want to calculate `T(t)`

```
T = \int_{0}^{t}\phi \left ( t-\tau  \right )\frac{\textup{d}\tau}{\tau ^{1/2}}
```

So the the singularity at tau = 0 makes "conv" not work. I've been fiddling with anonymous functions and using quadgk to handle the singularity and the like, but can't make anything work. I would have bet anything that this is a solved problem but can't find anything like it. Any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT: solved it this way:

```
function T = TCalc(time, power)

warning off MATLAB:quadgk:NonFiniteValue %suppress warning at the zero point

T=zeros(size(time));

for par = 1:numel(time)
    T(par) = s1(time(par));
end

function y = r1(t)
    y = interp1q(time,power,t');%notice that t is transposed! to make interp1q work.
    y = y'; 
end

function y = s1(tfin)
    y = quadgk(@(t) (r1(tfin-t))./t.^(0.5),0,tfin,'RelTol',1.e-2);
end
end
```

I guess, the inelegant trick here is to make Matlab think the experimental data is an analytical function by passing through interp1, and using quadgk to tolerate a singularity at the limit of integration. About one second for 1000-point vectors. Ignoring or setting the tau = 0 point to a small value doesn't work, it still perceives a singularity and the result is wrong.

Comment: You need to decide how you want the singularity handled. Maybe you just want to exclude \tau = 0?

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work too well...I made it work with this code. A bit clumsy but with relative tolerance low it works reasonably fast for my application.